# how can i access UIBezierPath that is drawn in draw(_ rect: CGRect)?

Tags: swift, uiview, core-graphics, calayer, uibezierpath

I'm drawing lines with UIBezierPath in draw(_ rect: CGRect) method previously i did tried that with CAShapeLayer but i wasn't able to select particular path and move it so i'm trying this, but after drawing i'm not able to access that BezierPath from view's subviews or it's sublayers and not directly from UIView. How can i access that bezierpath drawn in drawRect method so i can change it's position according to touches.

```
private var bezierPaths: [MyBezierPath] = [MyBezierPath]()

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)
    UIColor.orange.set()
    for path in bezierPaths {
        path.lineWidth = 4
        path.lineCapStyle = .round
        path.lineJoinStyle = .round
        path.stroke()
    }
}

    func drawingPath(_ path: [MyBezierPath]) {
    bezierPaths = path
}
```

like creating CAShapeLayer and setting layer.path = BezierPath like this :

```
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
        shapeLayer.lineJoin = .round
        shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [10, 10]
        shapeLayer.name = "ShapeLayer"
        self.canvas.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

if canvas.layer.sublayers != nil && canvas.layer.sublayers?.last?.name == "ShapeLayer" {
                guard let layer = canvas.layer.sublayers?.last as? CAShapeLayer else { return }
                layer.path = path.cgPath
            }
}
```

like this i can access layer.path but how can i do it for path drawn in draw(Rect:) method ?

Comment: @Sweeper i mean after adding that path to custom uiview how can i access path from that uiview. like after adding bezierpath to cashapelayer and add that layer to uiview i can access view's sublayers and create refference of calayer as cashapelayer and just access it's path

Comment: i didn't find any way to access that bezierpath from uiview after adding into it.

Comment: Why are you comparing this to layers? Directly drawing with `draw(_:)` is totally different from using layers. I don't see any connection here. What happens when you access `bezierPaths`? How exactly does that not work for you?

Comment: i want to select and move bezierpath strokes

Comment: @Sweeper it's drawn and added in uiview so there will be some way to access that path and it's properties right ?

Comment: "i want to select and move bezierpath strokes" Do you want to use [`apply`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624340-apply) on the path to apply a translation transform? But note that in any case, you have to *redraw* the transformed path in `draw(_:)` in order to have the change visible. And to have `draw(_:)` be called again, you need to call `setNeedsDisplay()`.

Comment: Doing this with layers is much more convenient, as you can just move the layers around, and set the layers' properties. Why don't you do it with layers instead? Make each stroke you want to control its own layer.

Comment: @Sweeper actually i previously did that but i wasn't able to differentiate exactly which line user is touching

Comment: i think i will have to identify that with HitTest method what you say @Sweeper?

Comment: because layers are same size as view so can't get touch on particular line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you're actually trying to do, overriding `draw(_:)` may not be the best approach.

For example, if you want to *animate* the drawn paths, it will be much easier if you are using `CAShapeLayer` as sublayers, or using subviews.

Also, shape layers are *highly optimized* ... if you write your own draw / animate functions you risk ending up with lesser-optimized code.

However, whichever approach you take, to "find the path" you want to use `contains(_ point: CGPoint)`

For example, if you have an array of `UIBezierPath`, with all paths relative to the top-left (`0,0`) of the view, on touch you could do:

```
// find a path that contains the touch point
if let touchedPath = bezierPaths.first(where: {$0.contains(point)}) {
    // do something with that path
}
```

If the paths are *not* relative to the top-left of the view - for example, if the path is relative to the layer position, or is part of a subview - you'd need to convert the touch point.

Here's a quick example that looks like this - on load, and then after dragging a few shapes around:

[image] [image]

We'll start with a simple "path" struct, which contains the bezier path and the color to use. We could add various other properties, such as line width, dash pattern, etc:

```
struct MyPath {
    var color: UIColor = .white
    var path: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
}
```

then we'll use this `UIView` subclass that will handle the drawing, as well as touches began/moved/ended:

```
class BezDrawView: UIView {
    
    var myPaths: [MyPath] = [] {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    
    // used to track path to move
    var activePath: MyPath?
    var startPoint: CGPoint = .zero
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        
        if myPaths.count > 0 {
            myPaths.forEach { p in
                p.color.set()
                p.path.stroke()
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let t = touches.first else { return }
        let point = t.location(in: self)
        // find a path that contains the touch point
        if let touchedPath = myPaths.first(where: {$0.path.contains(point)}) {
            self.activePath = touchedPath
            self.startPoint = point
            return
        }
    }
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let ap = activePath, let t = touches.first else { return }
        let point = t.location(in: self)
        // move the path by the distance the touch moved
        let tr = CGAffineTransform(translationX: point.x - startPoint.x, y: point.y - startPoint.y)
        ap.path.apply(tr)
        startPoint = point
        // this triggers draw(_:)
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        // done dragging
        activePath = nil
    }
    
}
```

and an example controller which defines some sample shapes (paths):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        let testBezDrawView = BezDrawView()
        testBezDrawView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.1, alpha: 1.0)
        testBezDrawView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(testBezDrawView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain bez draw view to all 4 sides with 20-points "padding"
            testBezDrawView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            testBezDrawView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            testBezDrawView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            testBezDrawView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
        ])
        
        // add some sample path shapes and colors
        let colors: [UIColor] = [
            .systemRed, .systemGreen, .systemBlue,
            .cyan, .magenta, .yellow, .orange, .green,
        ]
        let rects: [CGRect] = [
            CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 60, height: 60),
            CGRect(x: 180, y: 20, width: 40, height: 60),
            CGRect(x: 20, y: 120, width: 60, height: 100),
            CGRect(x: 200, y: 140, width: 50, height: 90),
            CGRect(x: 90, y: 220, width: 100, height: 60),
            CGRect(x: 220, y: 260, width: 80, height: 160),
            CGRect(x: 50, y: 360, width: 200, height: 100),
            CGRect(x: 150, y: 480, width: 120, height: 80),
        ]
        var somePaths: [MyPath] = []
        var i: Int = 0
        for (c, r) in zip(colors, rects) {
            var b = UIBezierPath()
            switch i % 4 {
            case 1:     // oval
                b = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: r)
            case 2:     // triangle shape
                b = UIBezierPath()
                b.move(to: CGPoint(x: r.minX, y: r.maxY))
                b.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: r.midX, y: r.minY))
                b.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: r.maxX, y: r.maxY))
                b.close()
            case 3:     // diamond
                b = UIBezierPath()
                b.move(to: CGPoint(x: r.minX, y: r.midY))
                b.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: r.midX, y: r.minY))
                b.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: r.maxX, y: r.midY))
                b.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: r.midX, y: r.maxY))
                b.close()
            default:    // rect
                b = UIBezierPath(rect: r)
            }
            b.lineWidth = 4
            b.lineCapStyle = .round
            b.lineJoinStyle = .round
            b.setLineDash([5, 10], count: 2, phase: 0)
            let p = MyPath(color: c, path: b)
            somePaths.append(p)
            i += 1
        }
        testBezDrawView.myPaths = somePaths
    }
    
}
```

Here's a video of it in use (too big to convert to gif and embed here):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/66awT.jpg

---

**Edit** *in response to comment...*

That needs very few changes to make it work with **shape layers** instead of `draw(_:)`.

We can use the same Translation Transform to "move" the path, then update the `.path` property of that path's associated layer:

```
    let tr = CGAffineTransform(translationX: point.x - startPoint.x, y: point.y - startPoint.y)
    active.path.apply(tr)
    activeLayer.path = activeParh.path.cgPath
```

I ***strongly, strongly*** recommend that you try to convert that sample code to shape layers on your own - it would be a good learning exercise.

But, if you run into trouble, here's a modified version...

First, we're going to use the. array index of the `MyPath` object to match with the sublayer index, so we need to make our struct `Equatable`:

```
struct MyPath: Equatable {
    var color: UIColor = .white
    var path: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
}
```

Then some minor changes to `BezDrawView` -- which we'll name `BezLayerView`:

```
class BezLayerView: UIView {
    
    var myPaths: [MyPath] = [] {
        didSet {
            // remove any existing layers
            if let subs = layer.sublayers {
                subs.forEach { lay in
                    lay.removeFromSuperlayer()
                }
            }
            // create layers for paths
            myPaths.forEach { p in
                let lay = CAShapeLayer()
                lay.lineWidth = 4
                lay.lineCap = .round
                lay.lineJoin = .round
                lay.lineDashPattern = [5, 10]
                lay.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
                lay.strokeColor = p.color.cgColor
                lay.path = p.path.cgPath
                layer.addSublayer(lay)
            }
        }
    }
    
    // used to track path to move
    var activeLayer: CAShapeLayer?
    var activePath: MyPath?
    var startPoint: CGPoint = .zero
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let t = touches.first, let subs = layer.sublayers else { return }
        let point = t.location(in: self)
        // find a path that contains the touch point
        if let touchedPath = myPaths.first(where: {$0.path.contains(point)}) {
            // find the layer associated with that path
            if let idx = myPaths.firstIndex(of: touchedPath) {
                if let lay = subs[idx] as? CAShapeLayer {
                    self.activePath = touchedPath
                    self.activeLayer = lay
                    self.startPoint = point
                }
            }
        }
    }
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let lay = activeLayer, let ap = activePath, let t = touches.first else { return }
        let point = t.location(in: self)
        // move the path by the distance the touch moved
        let tr = CGAffineTransform(translationX: point.x - startPoint.x, y: point.y - startPoint.y)
        ap.path.apply(tr)
        lay.path = ap.path.cgPath
        startPoint = point
    }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        // done dragging
        activeLayer = nil
        activePath = nil
    }
    
}
```

and an almost identical version of the controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        let testBezLayerView = BezLayerView()
        testBezLayerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.1, alpha: 1.0)
        testBezLayerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(testBezLayerView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain bez draw view to all 4 sides with 20-points "padding"
            testBezLayerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            testBezLayerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            testBezLayerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            testBezLayerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
        ])
        
        // add some sample path shapes and colors
        let colors: [UIColor] = [
            .systemRed, .systemGreen, .systemBlue,
            .cyan, .magenta, .yellow, .orange, .green,
        ]
        let rects: [CGRect] = [
            CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 60, height: 60),
            CGRect(x: 180, y: 20, width: 40, height: 60),
            CGRect(x: 20, y: 120, width: 60, height: 100),
            CGRect(x: 200, y: 140, width: 50, height: 90),
            CGRect(x: 90, y: 220, width: 100, height: 60),
            CGRect(x: 220, y: 260, width: 80, height: 160),
            CGRect(x: 50, y: 360, width: 200, height: 100),
            CGRect(x: 150, y: 480, width: 120, height: 80),
        ]
        var somePaths: [MyPath] = []
        var i: Int = 0
        for (c, r) in zip(colors, rects) {
            var b = UIBezierPath()
            switch i % 4 {
            case 1:     // oval
                b = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: r)
            case 2:     // triangle shape
                b = UIBezierPath()
                b.move(to: CGPoint(x: r.minX, y: r.maxY))
                b.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: r.midX, y: r.minY))
                b.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: r.maxX, y: r.maxY))
                b.close()
            case 3:     // diamond
                b = UIBezierPath()
                b.move(to: CGPoint(x: r.minX, y: r.midY))
                b.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: r.midX, y: r.minY))
                b.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: r.maxX, y: r.midY))
                b.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: r.midX, y: r.maxY))
                b.close()
            default:    // rect
                b = UIBezierPath(rect: r)
            }
            let p = MyPath(color: c, path: b)
            somePaths.append(p)
            i += 1
        }
        testBezLayerView.myPaths = somePaths
    }
    
}
```

The output and functionality should be indistinguishable from the `BezDrawView` implementation.

Comment: thanks DonMag for all your efforts, let me try this.

Comment: hey can you please tell me how can i apply move transform to CAShapeLayer's path? i'm doing it with CAShapeLayer as you said it's batter.

Comment: @rameshsanghar - see the **Edit** to my answer.